# AWS Cognito - Get google refresh_token and add scopes to access_token

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, google-api, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';    

Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: "Google" })
```

so I can create a new user to my user pool using google authentication. After the user is created I would like to use the google spreadsheet api. There are two issues on that. First, I go to cognito console and do some attribute mapping. In the google tab I map access_token and refresh_token to two custom attributes I created. But in the

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
```

I get only the access_token and not the refresh_token so after the access_token expires then, while I will still be logged in and able to access the AWS APIs, I will not be able to access the Google Apis, so I will need to login again only for that.

The second issue is that even if I have the access_token, I am not able to add the appropriate scopes in order to use the APIs that I want. Am I able to more scopes apart from the default ones?

```
   "scope": [
        "phone",
        "email",
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
    ],
```

like the

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
```

If I add this to supported scopes I get an error:

```
 Error handling auth response. Error: invalid_scope
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve it? I have the same issue regarding the scopes. For the first issue, I'd check that in Cognito, the hosted UI for this app client is set to use "Authorization code grant"

Comment: It seems that the easiest workaround is to create a lamda function accessing the google api in the backend, and then connect to the lamda function while being authenticated with cognito. Everything is handled out of the box this way.